# Adding current_value in a table column in sql server

Tags: insert, subquery, sequence, sql-server-2016

I want to insert the current value of a sequence (which is a Primary Key in table1) into a column of table2.
I am using : MS SQL SERVER 2016

QUERY I tried:

```sql
INSERT INTO [dbo].[Employee] ([EMP_ID], [DEPT_ID], [DESCRIPTION]) 
VALUES (NEXT VALUE FOR EMP_ID_SEQ, 
        SELECT current_value FROM sys.sequences WHERE [name]= 'DEPT_ID_SEQ', 
        NULL)
```

ERROR:

> Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'SELECT'.

If I run `SELECT current_value FROM sys.sequences WHERE [name]= 'DEPT_ID_SEQ'` separately, it works well.

The value of DEPT_ID is a FK to DEPT table and is also a sequence.
Let me know any alternative way to it. Preferably in a single statement since I've to mould it in liquibase tags and run the entire query via liquibase update.

Comment: A subquery needs to be within parenthesis (`()`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use an `INSERT INTO ... SELECT`:

```
INSERT INTO [dbo].[Employee] ([EMP_ID], [DEPT_ID], [DESCRIPTION])
CONVERT(int, SELECT NEXT VALUE FOR EMP_ID_SEQ), current_value, NULL
FROM sys.sequences WHERE [name] = 'DEPT_ID_SEQ';
```

Comment: It gives this: Implicit conversion from data type sql_variant to numeric is not allowed. Use the CONVERT function to run this query.

Comment: Then do what it says, @Veer . *Explicitly* `CONVERT`. That error cannot be more explicit that it already is.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @Tim learnt something new :)
But sadly, I had to look for other options due to complexities in liquibase:
Below query worked well and also easy to incorporate in liquibase.

```
INSERT INTO [dbo].[Employee] ([EMP_ID], [DEPT_ID], [DESCRIPTION]) 
VALUES (NEXT VALUE FOR EMP_ID_SEQ, 
        (select CAST(SELECT current_value FROM sys.sequences WHERE [name]= 'DEPT_ID_SEQ') As INT)), 
        NULL)
```